# How to use datasoure in ng2-ya-table?

Tags: grails, angular-cli, ngtable, groovyshell

In the documentation of `ng2-ya-table` the datasource function is written in this way :

```
public datasource: any = (request: any): Observable<any> => {
return this.service.getUsers(request);
}
```

And used like this :

```
<ng2-ya-table [options]="options" [columns]="columns" [datasource]="datasource" [paging]="paging">
</ng2-ya-table>
```

I don't want to use this function in this way because I have static

```
data = [
    {
        name: 'Patricia',
        email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org',
        username: 'Yes',
    },
    {
        name: 'Chelsey Dietrich',
        email: 'Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca',
        username: 'No',
    }
]
```

Is that possible or I am obliged to render observable type?
I tried a lot using static data but in vain

```
public datasource: any = {
    return this.data ;
}
```

why this function is not working?

Comment: Hoping someone answers you...I have same question and documentation for this module is poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
public datasource: any = (request: any): Observable<any> => {
  return Observable.of({
    recordsTotal: this.data.length,
    recordsFiltered: this.data.length,
    data: this.data
  });
}
```

Anyway, you need to perform pagination, sorting and filtering client side (the data source is an Observable in order to perform this operation server side).
For example (pagination only):

```
public datasource: any = (request: any): Observable<any> => {
  let page = (request.start / request.length) + 1;
  return Observable.of({
    recordsTotal: this.data.length,
    recordsFiltered: this.data.length,
    data: this.data.slice(request.length * (page - 1), request.length * page)
  });
}
```

Comment: The latest version now supports the local data source.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
public datasource: any = (request: any): Observable<any> => {
  return Observable.of(this.data);
}
```

but it causes a cascade of errors starting with:

> Ng2YaTableComponent.html:53 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'length' of undefined

If someone can improve this answer perhaps we can find an solution